# Timer that breaks when any input is given in Python

Tags: python, time

I am trying to find a way to create a timer in python that keeps counting while the user doesn't input anything. The goal is to then create a function that automatically backs up the data from the session to a separate JSON file if the time of inactivity exceeds 10 mins. If I start an infinite loop that breaks when there is an input it will stop the rest of the code from executing. Also using `time.time()` in the traditional way to measure execution time (subtract end from start) isn't useful here because I don't want to measure the execution time after a particular line. How could I go about this? Thanks!

Bellow is a simplified format of the block I wish to apply this to.

```
def run(self):
    run = True
    while run:
        command_input = input("Please type your command"):
        # some function that either breaks when user inputs or starts series of action if time exceeds 10 mins
        if command == "a":
        function_one()
        else:
        function_two()
```

#### EDIT - SOLUTION IN MY SCRIPT'S CONTEXT

```
class Session:
    def __init__(self):
        self.last_command_timing = time.time()
    def run(self):
        run = True
        threading.Thread(target=self.check_time_limit).start()
        while run:
            command_input = input("Please type your command"):
            if command == "a":
                self.last_command_timing = time.time()
                function_one()
            else:
                self.last_command_timing = time.time()
                function_two()
    def check_time_limit(self):
        while True:
             if time.time() - self.last_command_timing> 600 :
                  backup_function()
                  break
    def backup_function(self):
        # some backing up func
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input() function in python blocks the thread. So if you want to use input and save something simultaneously, you have to create another thread.

```
import threading
import time

lastActive = time.time()

# function which is running in the background and saves the data if needed
def save():
   while True:
       if time.time() - lastActive > 600:
           # Save ...

# This call starts a new thread
threading.Thread(target=save).start()


# The main while loop
while True:
    command = input("Please type your command")
    lastActive = time.time()
    
    # Process the command ...
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. It doesn't mention in your answer how the save() func is going to monitor the inputs in while loop. Would I call on the save() function from within the while loop?  I don't really understand the logic behind your code could you clarify?

Comment: This just gave me an idea. This is actually part of a class (check modified code sample). Could I add a variable in the `__init__` function that holds a value with a `time.time()` value, and whenever a command is input it resets it, meanwhile a function that runs simultaneously through threading and constantly checks that `self.variable` in the `__init__` function?

Comment: @MahmoudHosny Yeah, when something has changed from the data, you could set a variable, if it's in a class or not doesn't matter. Inside the save function, you have to check if you want to save it now, so if it's inactive for over 10 min and something has changed. You don't have to call it from the main while loop. The save function is running in parallel to the main function. I'll update my code to show these things.

Comment: Hi, yeah I was working on that in the context of my code while you were answering. Could you please check the new edit with a potential solution in my question and see if this a correct format? Thanks!

Comment: I think a few things could be improved in your possible solution. You say while run, but run is always true, so you could write while true directly. Before each input, you create a new thread. And these created threads never get destroyed. So you could ran out of memory. This could be easiliy fixed by moving the thread creating outside the loop. But the rest is exactly what I meant with my solution.

Comment: Yeah but the `run` variable can be turned to `False` later on in the script. I did change the thread to be outside the loop though, thanks! But the overall logic stands and there are no problems with the formatting?

Comment: I don't see anything that could cause trouble. It should be good.

Comment: Hi, so as it turns out, for the purpose of my code, it is kinda necessary to create a new thread for each input. Is there a way to manually close the previous thread every time it loops and creates a new thread? I am reading an article saying that `threading.Event` and `thread.join()` both can be potential solutions for this but not sure which is best in the context of my code. Thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252593/discussion-between-formularossa-and-mahmoud-hosny).

Answer (score 1):

This might be helpful. Good luck!

https://pypi.org/project/pytimedinput/

Edit: including example, as per request.

First install: `pip install pytimedinput`

Example:

```
from pytimedinput import timedInput
userText, timedOut = timedInput("Please, do enter something: ")
if(timedOut):
    print("Timed out when waiting for input.")
    print(f"User-input so far: '{userText}'")
else:
    print(f"User-input: '{userText}'")
```